# Airdrop Over Wired Connection?

Tags: macos, ios, airdrop

I often shoot a photo with my phone and then want to see it on my Macbook Pro. Sometimes the iPhone is actually supplying the Net connection for the MBP, so I cannot use AirDrop! What's the easiest way to get a single photo from my phone to my Mac without sending a message to someone?

Comment: I've not had problems tethering and sharing via AirDrop as they work independently. What specifically makes you "cannot use AirDrop" - is there an error message? What OS on the Mac? What OS on the iOS? (versions and maybe the build if you're pre-release)

Answer (score 2):

Open Image Capture or the Photos app on the Mac and connect the phone over USB. That's the easiest way to pick one photo to import.

Other methods involve setting up sync or some apps to do the syncing if AirDrop is not reliable enough for your needs. (you're not alone there on depending on it - wireless interference that can be reasonable encountered these days can render AirDrop less than reliable in my experience)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a USB-C iPhone (iPhone 15 Pro and above), Airdrop seems to automatically use the wired connection. You transfer the file normally, and the notification on MacOS says "Using Wired connection".

I couldn't find an official mention of the feature, but there's [a few](https://www.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/1807654/airdrop_using_wired_connection/) [user reports](https://mastodon.social/@_inside/112043390973974454) about the feature.